# Not able to run basic react

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I know this is stupid question, but I can't figure where I went wrong.

This is `.html` file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>REACT JS</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"
      crossorigin
    ></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

my `.js`

```
alert('alert');
ReactDOM.render(<h1>Hello, world!</h1>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

The problem is when reactDOM is not commented out even the `alert` is not working(When I commented out the react part `alert` is doing fine).
Is there something else I should do before using react.js, I'm super new to react.js

Comment: I recommend you use the create-react-app to get started with react. Simply run in your console ```npx create-react-app your_app_name```

Comment: Your code needs to be transpile mate since it contains jsx which browser doesn’t understand

Comment: @tmhao2005 Can you please tell me how to do that

Answer (score 1):

If you want to only see how React works with `es5` javascript style without using the latest javascript. You can create your component by `React.createElement` function. Put the following code to your `main.js` file:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  React.createElement("h1", null, "Hello world"),
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

But in order to take advantage of using `JSX`, you can try to install a demo project by using `create-react-app` which set up everything for you, you just simply write code without caring about how to build.

Answer (score 0):

React JS is a library. You can't use its syntax and features unless you include the library itself in your project. Please visit https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're learning React and need a place to run react, you could try using a platform like Plunkr:

Here is a link to a quick react demo I created on plunkr: `https://plnkr.co/edit/github:plnkr/starters/v1.4.0/templates/react?open=Hello.js&deferRun=1&preview`

If you want to run react on your dev machine using create-react-app, then follow this steps:

1. You'd need first to install node:
   https://nodejs.org/en/
2. Create an empty folder using the command prompt (Windows) or
   Terminal (Mac) and type the command `mkdir myreactproject`
3. Then navigate to the folder you just created (myreactproject) and
   run the command `create-react-app .`
4. Once completed you can test your program by running `npm start`

Furthermore, since you're new to react I'd recommend learning here, it's free:

```
https://scrimba.com/g/glearnreact
```